# Can I loop through class/model names in Fluent API to configure entities in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In my ASP.NET / EF Core application I have several models (classes) (say 20) all with the column names such as

```
createdAt
modifiedAt
...
isVisible
```

that I want to configure with the same attributes (for example, Required=True, DefaultValue(0), unique values) etc

I have been doing it like this (Model1, 2)

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Model1>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.Column1)
            .IsUnique();

 modelBuilder.Entity<Model2>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.Column1)
            .IsUnique();   

 modelBuilder.Entity<Model3>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.Column1)
            .IsUnique();
```

This is very tiresome and lot of copy, paste etc

Is there an easier way to do this ..using foreach..for example

```
foreach (var someModel in <loop through all models here> I don't know how) 
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<someModel>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.Column1)
            .IsUnique();   
}
```

Comment: Make them inherit from an interface

Comment: IMHO, saving characters at the expense of clarity is generally not worth it.  Leave your model configuration explicit.  Perhaps nobody will thank you for it, but nobody will be frustrated by the bottled magic later, either.

Comment: Would be better to use a base class with these properties and inherit from with all your models